# Best practice of API call from Activities

Tags: android, performance, api

I am in a bit trouble finding out the best practice. I need an expert opinion on this. My scenario is I have an API which returns me the list of applicants for a particular job. In my parent activity, I have the list of jobs and I am asking that, should I call the API on button click from the parent activity and pass it over to the child or should I just transact the activities and call the API from the child activity? Please give me a good advice to improve the user experience and speed. Because the retrieved JSON will be quite huge in terms of data. Thank you

Comment: Please don't downvote please read the question before downvoting

Comment: Please don't ask opinion based questions please read [ask] before asking a question

Comment: I read that and didn't find anything that opposes me in posting this, i am in need of an experienced guy's opinion so i thought that developers like you love to redirect and want to teach good practices. Sorry if this question looks irrelevant to you. Palm posted a direction rather than spending time to comment here with showing only my question's irrelevance, you could have at least give a good opinion and mention 'don't post this type questions' anyway thank you for your time too. I will try to avoid these kind of questions.

Comment: *I need an expert opinion on this* - a question can not get more opinion based than this, and such questions are not a good fit for stackoverflow. Understand that we do not want such questions to be posted here, and answering them either in an answer or in a comment encourages others to ask such questions as well. We do not want that. Yes I could have answered your question in a comment, but I purposely didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In General

If the data is not used by the **main activity** itself, there is **no** reason to make the API call from the main activity. Call the child activity when the user clicks the button and start fetching the data in the child activity.

### User experience

If the size of the data is huge, like you explained, or the user has a poor internet connection, you obviously need to give the user feedback in form of a loading animation in the child activity. As an example you could use a library like [this](https://github.com/florent37/FiftyShadesOf).

### Performance

The will be no performance difference between fetching the data in the main or in the child activity. To gain overall performance, make shure to cache the fetched data. 
In the child activity you could load the data (list of applicants for a particular job) in small portions to quickly show the first few records. This will also strongly increase the users experience.

I hope this answers you question in a proper way.
*Sorry for poor english.*

Comment: Thank you for your time, thank you for your feedback